# How to connect to DB2 in robotframework (using Ride)

Tags: python-2.7, db2, robotframework

I can connect to the DB2 (IBM AS400) in Java Spring successfully using library jt400.jar and JDBC Driver:  com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver

But not successful in Robotframework

I tried to use below code:

```
Connect To Database Using Custom Params    jaydebeapi    'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver','jdbc:db2://10.53.x.x/XABZ:user=USER1;password=PASS1'
    Check If Exists In Database    select * from lib.btmtran where tmtxseq = 187822
    Disconnect From Database
```

I got the error

> ***** Out of Package Error Occurred (2018-07-24 16:55:25.3) *****
>
> Exception stack trace: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error:
>   SQLCODE=-805, SQLSTATE=51002, SQLERRMC=NULLID.SYSSH200;00;S6576b3b
>   , DRIVER=4.21.29
>       com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(kd.java:815)
>       com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(kd.java:66)

How to fix it ?

Comment: You may need to bind  the file db2clipk.bnd to the database. This file comes with the Db2-client .  Binding the file results in the creation of the missing package (SYSSH200) in the database.  Refer to the Db2 Knowledge center for details. Other bindfiles may also need to be bound.

Comment: But why not error when using jdbctemplate in java. For example Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:as400://viper", "******", "******");

Comment: python uses the CLI libraries and driver , not the java driver.